# Unable to run powershell script with parameters from within python

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell

I'm trying to run a powershell script (with parameters) from within python (**version 3.8.3**), and after reading many stackoverflow posts I came to the following code:

```
import subprocess

path = r"'C:\Program Files\Company\Some space\Some-Script.ps1'"
args = r"-UserId abcd1234 -PageUri https://example.com/testapp -Privileges @('ReadOnly', 'ReadWrite')"
full_command = f'"& {path} {args}"';

result = subprocess.run(['powershell.exe', full_command ], capture_output=True)

print('printing out ...')
print(result.stdout)

print('printing error ...')
print(result.stderr)
```

However when I run the above python script, the following output is generated .... which is basically just dumping the powershell command back out without actually running it (by the looks of it)

```
printing out ...
b"& 'C:\\Program Files\\Company\\Some space\\Some-Script.ps1' -UserId abcd1234 -PageUri https://example.com/testapp -Privileges @('ReadOnly', 'ReadWrite')\r\n"
printing error ...
b''
```

The python code above was generated using the following Windows shell command, which works fine:

```
powershell.exe "& 'C:\Program Files\Company\Some space\Some-Script.ps1' -UserId abcd1234 -PageUri https://example.com/testapp -Privileges @('ReadOnly', 'ReadWrite')"
```

Can someone kindly tell me what is the issue with my python code ?

Comment: See if `full_command = f'& {path} {args}'` helps.